# Display multiple currency for multiple stores

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, multicurrency

we have 2 different stores in our site.

for one  store we have to display currency symbol as "Rs" [Indian Rupee]

we followed as below image. its working.

[image]

for another store we need to display currency symbol as "$" [ US DOllar ]

but its not working. Is it require any code changes or extension.

or will it work only if i use multiple websites instead of multiple stores ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add the Currency Rate in admin:

```
System >> Manage Currency >> Rates
```

Add currency rate here and check, Hope this will help

Comment: i am seeing [this](http://prntscr.com/axgd6y) in backend , can you please guide me how to add currency rates?

Comment: add 0.015 in USD input box and save currency rate or Click on import and save currency rates

Comment: Nice, I saw in some posts its not possible without creating 2 websites. but Its working fine.

Comment: now 0.015 is because of [this](http://prnt.sc/axgljt) is i need to update the value manually

or is there any automated process ?

Comment: No need to update currency Rate manually, Use the webservice  service and set the cron for this in admin So it automatically import the updated rates

Comment: what i did is i clicked on "import" , than i entered `0.0150` under "USD" textfield and than cicked on
"`Save currency rates`". cron is running in our server. is it correct ? or anything else ?

Comment: Go to System >> Configuration >> Currency Setup >> Scheduled Import Settings
set the Schedule here

Comment: is [this](http://prnt.sc/axh4a9) enough?

Comment: Yes this is enough

Comment: your name was really nice, i dont know why you changed it :-) Thanks a lot for your time & patience.

Comment: i just said the fact :-)